# Where is Nancy's second outfit?

Tags: stranger-things-the-game

I’m playing through the Mobile game. I have found everything except Nancy’s second outfit. Where is it?

Answer (score 3):

It's in Hawking's Middle School. Enter and go one room up, then right twice and there is a pipe where you have to use Will. Enter the pipe and there it is.